# Push sprites to sprite vector once at beginning of game

Tags: c++, sfml, game-development

I'm currently making asteroids in SFML c++. I want to spawn 5 asteroids when the game starts. But I don't want them to keep re-spawning if an asteroid gets deleted from the vector.

## Game.cpp

```
        // Push asteroids to asteroid vector
        if (asteroid_vector.size() < max_asteroids)
        {
            asteroid_vector.push_back(asteroid);
        }
```

This pushes the asteroids created into the asteroid vector. but this if statement is located in the game loop so whenever an asteroid is destroyed a new one takes its place.

I tried taking the if statement out of the game loop but then it only creates a single asteroid. I want it to generate 5 asteroids at the start of the game but not generate anymore unless I tell it to push more asteroids to the vector.

Comment: You may want something like `while (asteroid_vector.size() < max_asteroids) { ... }` before your game loop but then you would end up with 5 copies of the same asteroid. Maybe that's what you want, maybe not.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I found a way that works. I can do it the way I've been but every time an asteroid gets destroyed decrement max_asteroids by 1 so then it doesn't spawn back. then if I want to spawn more I can just increment max_asteroids.

Comment: i mean, what about just not putting that line of code in the game loop? Put it before you go into the game loop. Have a level initialization function that gets called once and put it there, for example.

Answer (score 0):

SFML main function looks something like this (the basic skeleton):

```cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    // create the window
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "My window");

    // run the program as long as the window is open
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        // check all the window's events that were triggered since the last iteration of the loop
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            // "close requested" event: we close the window
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        // clear the window with black color
        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

        // draw everything here...
        // window.draw(...);

        // end the current frame
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now lets explain the parts of the code so that it's easier to understand where things should be located.
At first we have the 'initialisation phase' in which all are needed components, objects, variables are created and set to specific starting values. This phase starts at the beginning of the main function up until the start of the main while loop that plays and controlls the window. Here it is cropped out of the code:

```cpp
// create the window
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "My window");
```

You can have any variable, object, or init function do init for all the things you need here. This happens just once. If you need to do something for more than one thing, use a loop to do it in this section.

Next is the while loop in which everything inside the window happens. Inside it we have the events part, and then the per frame part. Events only happen once every event occours. Let's say a click. your click could last 250 frames but you only want it to register once, so you should put it inside the event part. Lastly we have the per frame part which like the name suggests happens every frame no matter what. This is where you want to put anything that checks the game for something, the things that draw the frames, the things u want happening every frame.

Now what you seem to want is to create lets say 5 asteroids at the beginning of the game and not have them automatically added during the game. As you can see if you put your code in the "every frame" part, it would check your if statement every frame thus no matter how many times you delete the asteroid there will always be 5 of them. The best place to put this spawning is well in the init phase where you create all you need. You have 5 of them thus you need a loop to handle it and you just add it before your while game loop like so:

```cpp
int main()
{
    // create the window
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "My window");


    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        asteroid_vector.push_back(asteroid);
    //or while loop doesnt matter
    while (asteroid_vector.size() < max_asteroids)
        asteroid_vector.push_back(asteroid);

    // run the program as long as the window is open
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        //...
    }

    return 0;
}
```